# UIImage View reset/empty

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

HI all I am developing an iOS app which allows the user to pick an image using UIImagePicker. Now I have to create the action that restores the UIIageView with no image inside. can anyone help me with code?

```
-(IBAction)emptyImage{

//code to empty the UIImageView

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
-(IBAction)emptyImage{

   imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"noimage.png"];  (OR)

   imgview.image= nil; (OR)

   imgview.image= [UIImage imageNamed:@""];


}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use  this one....

```
-(IBAction)emptyImage
{
     imageView.image=nil
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
-(IBAction)emptyImage
{

   NSArray *remoVeSunBVIew = [self.view subviews];
      for(UIView *viw in remoVeSunBVIew)
      {
          [viw removeFromSuperview];
      }
}
```

Hope this will help you..

Comment: From where scrlFirstScroll came? What is it? How will it empty imageview?

Comment: @Durgaprasad now i changed scrlFirstScroll to self.view

Answer (score 1):

**iOS empty UIImageView**

Additionally you can try to use

```
UIImage()
```

Comment: Why not simply set the `image` property to `nil`?